# Rails duplicating item method renders edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to duplicate active Item records.

On my items_controller:

```
  def duplicate
      @item = Item.find((params[:id]))
      @item_copy = @item.dup
      render 'new'
  end
```

I call it from show view with:

```
<%= link_to "copy", duplicate_item_path(params[:id]) %>
```

routes:

```
  resources :items do
      member do
        get 'duplicate'
      end
    end
```

When I click the link, it takes me to edit @item.

If I change my form to

```
<%= simple_form_for(@item_copy) do |f| %>
```

I get expected results, a new form filled with @item attributes.

Do I really need a separate form for duplicating or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `@item` correctly in the action:

```
def duplicate
  @item = Item.find(params[:id]).dup
  render 'new'
end
```

In this case you can have only one form with `<%= simple_form_for(@item) do |f| %>` for both actions.